# Vertical navigation in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create a vertical sidebar in Bootstrap 3. The sidebar would be for navigation and should be stretched to the end of te page. The page layout should look something like [this](http://i1302.photobucket.com/albums/ag123/ThibaultG4U/mockupBT3_zpsudtmkhpe.png)

I'm getting close by nesting columns, but the only problem is that the sidebar has to have a max-width of 200px. If I do this via CSS however, there is some unwanted padding between the last column and the right edge of the browser.

I hope my codepen can help clarify what I'm trying to do: http://codepen.io/ThibaultG4U/pen/vNEQLY

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#mainNav {
  background-color: red;
}

#sideNav {
  background-color: green;
  max-width: 200px;
}


#col1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#col2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
<nav id="mainNav">
    <p>Main Nav</p>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <nav id="sideNav" class="col-lg-3">
            <p>Side Nav</p>
        </nav>

        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <div id="col1" class="col-lg-6">
                <p>Col 1</p>
            </div>

            <div id="col2" class="col-lg-6">
                <p>col 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Does anyone of you have an idea how to fix this? :)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

Create a div for the `sidebar` at 200px and add margin-left in a like amount to a div against it (`main-content` in the example) for the page content to sit.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background: #eee;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.sidebar-fixed {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 5px 18px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #eee;
}
ul.sidebar-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
}
ul.sidebar-list > li {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
ul.sidebar-list > li > a {
  color: #3e474f;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar-default .collapse .navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-header a.navbar-brand {
  color: #3e474f;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background: #3e474f;
}
.main-content {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar-fixed {
    display: none;
  }
  .main-content {
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-default .collapse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #3e474f;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"> Register</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Login</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="sidebar-fixed">
    <ul class="sidebar-list">
      <li> <a href="#"> About</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> Contact</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> Products</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> Blog</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="well">Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux
        de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960 grâce
        à la vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum, et, plus récemment, par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker.Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition
        et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a
        pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960 grâce à la vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum,
        et, plus récemment, par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker.Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem I</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you use two `.col-lg-6` classes inside one `col-lg-12`. You need to use larger parent block for `.col-lg-6`. As minimum you need `.col-lg-12`:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div id="col1" class="col-lg-6">
        <p>Col 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="col2" class="col-lg-6">
        <p>col 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

To looks perfectly you need use `.col-lg-10` with two `.col-lg-5`:

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <div id="col1" class="col-lg-5">
        <p>Col 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="col2" class="col-lg-5">
        <p>col 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and should apply this CSS:

```
#col1 {
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
}



 @media (min-width: 1200px) .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9 {
    float: right;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px)
.col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```